# How can I get Azure Devops to recognise that a subscription connection has a new access token?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

We have a service connection from Azure DevOps to an Azure Subscription that has been stable and working for several years. A few days ago, the key that it used to retrieve an access token expired, and deployments began to fail.

We refreshed the key, but now when we try to run a deployment we get the same `Could not fetch Access Token for azure` error, as if the key is cached somewhere.

If we create a new subscription connection, then deployment succeeds, but we have dozens of deployments using the same subscription connection, so it is a large job to replace them all.

How can we get Azure to recognise correctly that we have refreshed the key - or are there steps in renewing token access that we have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update a created Service Connection in **Project Settings -- Service Connection -- Update service Connection**.

[image]

You could use the full version of the service connection dialog

If you are using  preview feature of service connections. All you have to do is navigate to the service connection, click "Edit" in the upper right corner and then save without any changes.

[image]

More details take a look at this similar question:

- [Azure App Service deploy Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107017/azure-app-service-deploy-failed-to-get-resource-id-for-resource-type-microsoft)
- [Azure devops service connection expired and cannot edit/renew](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/929344/azure-devops-service-connection-expired-and-cannot.html)

Comment: Yes, that worked - we're using the preview so I updated the description and saved. Many thanks.