# Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' and resource name 'AppService' during Azure DevOps continuous deployment

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

When I try to deploy the .net app service to azure using azure devops CD, I got a below Error:

```
 Error: Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' and resource name 'AppService'. Error: connect ENETUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80
    Failed to add release annotation. TypeError: Cannot read property 'getApplicationSettings' of undefined
    UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getApplicationURL' of undefined
```

I could not able to get the root cause for it. Help me out here. Attached the image for it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfHTy.png

Comment: Similar thread for your reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107017/azure-app-service-deploy-failed-to-get-resource-id-for-resource-type-microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check if the Service Endpoint that you are using has permissions for the App Service ?

You can do this by navigating to

**`project settings -> service connections -> new service connection -> selected azure resource manager -> selected service principal authentication INSTEAD OF managed identity authentication ->`**