# AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys are expired

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops

Am using Azuredevops & Azure cloud, my deployment got failed with this error AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys are expired. Am not sure where to check this , can someone help me on this?

Comment: your azure devops pipeline runs using a service principal. when you create the service principal, the dedault client_secret/password expired after a year. check the service principal you;re using and create/generate a new client_secret/password for this SP

Comment: Could you elaborate your issue? Did you run a pipeline to deploy to Azure in DevOps? How was your pipeline like? When did you get this error? Please share detailed log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the error code here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes

> AADSTS7000222: InvalidClientSecretExpiredKeysProvided - The provided
> client secret keys are expired. Visit the Azure portal to create new
> keys for your app, or consider using certificate credentials for added
> security: https://aka.ms/certCreds

Assuming you got the error from pipeline during deployment. Check the service connection you use and update the key or create a new service connection.

Comment: Thank you , it worked after  deleting the old one in certificates&secrets in Azure portal and created new one.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but the same code if I am running at my local machine, it is working fine without any error or warning but as I am running into Azure DevOps, it is giving AADSTS7000222 error.

Comment: how can we find the service connection?

Comment: @RailsDeveloper 's question seems especially relevant to me since the error `AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys for app '***' are expired.` doesn't seem to tell me which app is having the issue.

Any idea how I can find out which app "***" is?

Answer (score 14):

The error AADSTS7000222 occurs when you need to update an expired client secret for a service connection in Azure DevOps. [The steps to do this are outlined in the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#failedToObtainJWT).

> 1. Go to **Project settings** > **Service connections**, and then select the service connection you want to modify.
> 2. Select **Edit** in the upper-right corner, and then make any change to your service connection. The easiest and recommended change is to
>    add a description.
> 3. Select **Save** to save the service connection. Don't try to verify the service connection at this step.
> 4. Exit the service connection edit window, and then refresh the service connections page.
> 5. Select **Edit** in the upper-right corner, and now select **Verify**.
> 6. Select **Save** to save your service connection.

Comment: I followed these steps, but in the Edit screen, there didn't seem to be a Verify option in Azure DevOps. Has it been removed since this answer was posted?

Comment: @BleakMorn I just checked this, the Verify button is still there. You should see it below the 'Resource group' dropdown, and above the 'Service connection name' field.

Comment: Initially this did not work for me because I had started the job before updating the service connection, however after following these steps exactly and only then starting the job running, did they then work.  I guess they are fed into the job at startup rather than being used on demand in the process.

Comment: Getting "TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id:" in Step 3?

Answer (score 0):

The key used for service connection is expired.Please refer the bellow mention link.

[Azure App Service deploy Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107017/azure-app-service-deploy-failed-to-get-resource-id-for-resource-type-microsoft/58109353#58109353)