# Getting Error: Could not fetch access token for Azure when deploying using Azure DEVOPS

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy a APP using Azure DEVOPS CI/CD Pipelines, however I am receiving the following error:

***2022-01-19T19:55:37.5454688Z ##[error]Error: Failed to fetch App Service 'xxxxx' publishing credentials. Error: Could not fetch access token for Azure. Verify if the Service Principal used is valid and not expired. For more information refer https://aka.ms/azureappservicedeploytsg***

I checked the Client Secret and they are expired. I asked to the admin create a new one, however still receiving the same error when deploying.

Anyone have an idea? Can be because we still have these two expired keys? Do I have to change something in appsettings? (I do not think so right?)

[image: se]

Answer (score 18):

When getting this error on my build pipeline, I was able to follow the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63954400/aadsts7000222-the-provided-client-secret-keys-are-expired/71710265#71710265) (copied below) to solve it. The only other thing I had to do was select a 'Resource group' before hitting Verify in step 5.

> 1. Go to **Project settings** > **Service connections**, and then select the service connection you want to modify.
> 2. Select **Edit** in the upper-right corner, and then make any change to your service connection. The easiest and recommended change is to
>    add a description.
> 3. Select **Save** to save the service connection. Don't try to verify the service connection at this step.
> 4. Exit the service connection edit window, and then refresh the service connections page.
> 5. Select **Edit** in the upper-right corner, and now select **Verify**.
>    (You may need to select a valid **Resource group** first if one isn't already selected.)
> 6. Select **Save** to save your service connection.

Comment: Thanks for this one. Never woulda guessed...

Answer (score 4):

I tried this first (there was an expired secret):

In my failing Azure Pipleine in the "Azure Web App Deploy" task, I selected the Manage link in the Azure subscription section.
This took my to the Azure Portal project where I selected the Service connections option from the meu under Pipelines.
I clicked on "Manage Service Principal" and an expired Client Secret was listed. I generated a new one and deleted the old one.

When that did not fix my issue, I then did the following:

Went to Azure Dev Ops Project Setting:
Pipeline > Service connections
My Production app has a Github Service connection, while all the other have an Azure Service connection.

So, I added a New service connection (Azure Resource Manager in my case).
Updated my Pipeline with the new connection and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I had to configure the new Secret Key in AZURE DEVOPS Connection.

Thanks

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: after you did that, did you have to paste secret elsewhere?